# Print Multiple Content Header Types

Tags: php, header, http-headers, imagick

I am trying to convert a pdf into an image using Imagick and print multiple pages. The problem I am running into is using the header( "Content-Type: image/jpeg" ); for each page. It will only print the first page. When finished the image is set to a background to a page. My code looks like this:

```
$im = new imagick('filename.pdf');
$im->setImageFormat( "jpg" );

header( "Content-Type: image/jpeg" );
for ($i = 0; $i < $im->getNumberImages(); $i++) {

    $temp_image=new imagick("iptlock_media/files/s8czV4rz4Ge5YMFKsLSu.pdf[$i]");
    $temp_image->setImageFormat( "jpg" );
    echo $temp_image;
}//end foreach
```

Can anyone please advise how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to output several jpeg images to one header, which I don't think is possible.  Have you considered outputting the images to file and then outputting HTML to display all the images?

Comment: I thought about doing that but wouldn't that file take up space and have to be managed? Like ensured to be deleted later?

Comment: Yes, this is true.  A simple script that reads the contents of the generated image folder and deletes images older than an hour/day/week (or whatever makes sense for your application) would handle this.  Schedule it to run periodically with a cron job and your maintenance is automated.